# .Net Core and Windows Authentication in IIS 8 Failing

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

I have a .Net Core 1.0 web application targeting framework 4.6 that uses Windows Authentication (intranet site).  It runs fine in development environment under IIS Express.

In startup.cs I have:

```
services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => {
            options.ForwardWindowsAuthentication = true;
          });
```

Once deployed to IIS 8 in Windows Server 2012, however, the application errors out on the line:

```
var userName = context.User.Identity.Name;
```

With "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.  In web.config, I have:

```
    <system.web>
       <authentication mode="Windows" />
       <authorization>
          <deny users="?" />
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

In IIS Manager under "Authentication" for the site, everything is disabled except for "Windows Authentication" as well.  Another ASP.NET MVC 4 site on that same server with same settings in IIS works fine.   Anything else I can try to get this working??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Config settings below resolved this issue, specifically the forwardWindowsAuthToken=true:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="<path to app>"  arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="<outpath>" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" />
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
  </system.webServer>
```